# some problem with SSIS script component code, Sql Server 2008

Tags: c#-3.0, ssis

I have a flat file whose structure is as

```
Id  Value
1   1,2,3
2   4,5
```

The output needs to as

```
ID  Value
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
```

I have a flat file source and a script component which is being made as asynchronous. And in the script editor I have written the below code

```
 public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
        {
              MyOutputBuffer.AddRow(); 
               string[] arr = Row.Column1.Split(',');
              foreach (string s in arr)
              {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0))
                {
                      MyOutputBuffer.ID = Row.Column0;
                      MyOutputBuffer.Values = s;
                      MyOutputBuffer.AddRow();
                }
              }        
        }
        public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
        {
            while (Buffer.NextRow())
            {
                Input0_ProcessInputRow(Buffer);
            }

            if (Buffer.EndOfRowset())
            {
                MyOutputBuffer.SetEndOfRowset();
            }
        }
```

But I am getting the below output

```
Id  Value
NULL    NULL
1   1
1   2
1   3
NULL    NULL
2   4
2   5
NULL    NULL
```

What is wrong in the program.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Got the fix

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {     

        string[] arr = Row.Column1.Split(',');
        foreach (string s in arr)
        {
            MyOutputBuffer.AddRow();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0))
            {
                MyOutputBuffer.ID = Row.Column0;
                MyOutputBuffer.Values = s;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to go ahead and flag this as the answer so people know it is answered without having to open.  :-)